# Disparando um método .scroll no dispositivo mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile, rolamento

Eu estou tentando utilizar o método .scroll do Jquery da seguinte maneira, quando o usuário rolar o scroll uma alteração qualquer aconteça.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $('.exemplo').css('color', 'red');
})
```

```css
.exemplo {
  height: 250px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="exemplo">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur eros lorem, convallis eu tincidunt sit amet, faucibus vitae elit. Cras non hendrerit lectus, a sodales ex. Aenean sed massa gravida, aliquam est eget, molestie lacus. Duis in bibendum
  arcu, sed dictum nulla. Mauris eu tincidunt neque, eu tristique ex. Ut sit amet ipsum quis odio ullamcorper accumsan eu id sapien. Pellentesque imperdiet velit vitae nibh tincidunt, quis interdum nisi suscipit. Pellentesque ex dui, dignissim sit amet
  ex ac, posuere sollicitudin turpis. Fusce ullamcorper bibendum arcu a fermentum. Donec vitae ornare dui. Suspendisse pulvinar at velit vel tincidunt. Ut ac posuere turpis. Fusce consectetur, tellus a tempor ultrices, nisi eros elementum massa, id suscipit
  urna neque vel sapien. Integer cursus enim ligula, ac varius nisi tincidunt et. Sed vel purus lectus. Maecenas sed ipsum ex. Curabitur tincidunt tincidunt quam ac tincidunt. In facilisis leo est, ac cursus risus rhoncus nec. Maecenas finibus enim sed
  commodo hendrerit. Maecenas eu eros est. Praesent efficitur congue nulla. Donec in nisi nibh. Sed mi turpis, volutpat eu fermentum vitae, vestibulum sed mi. Etiam ac ullamcorper erat. Curabitur justo felis, tempus sed dignissim vestibulum, hendrerit
  ut sapien. Nunc sagittis in turpis at feugiat. Duis nulla augue, malesuada nec nunc ac, auctor cursus diam. Vestibulum interdum suscipit magna. Pellentesque aliquam tincidunt risus in pharetra. Aliquam mi odio, sollicitudin eget velit ac, commodo aliquet
  lorem. Cras pulvinar leo nibh, sit amet pulvinar purus vulputate sit amet. Proin sit amet sapien odio. Maecenas nisi nunc, scelerisque in lobortis at, tempor et eros. Phasellus feugiat massa ut sollicitudin pharetra. Suspendisse varius, purus quis volutpat
  laoreet, velit mi elementum nisi, in finibus magna metus sed erat. Aliquam tortor dolor, volutpat a mollis quis, facilisis id lectus. Pellentesque hendrerit molestie nisl, vel aliquet nisi. Vestibulum nec aliquam ante, ut fringilla lacus. Morbi commodo
  urna in pharetra aliquam. Cras non lorem nec libero varius semper. Aenean ac ex ut diam mattis blandit. Cras quis sem et augue commodo placerat. Mauris sollicitudin feugiat mollis. Pellentesque tempus interdum tortor in mollis. Integer nisi felis, sodales
  vitae neque eu, fringilla scelerisque diam. Duis et egestas enim. Nunc convallis lectus id bibendum commodo. Praesent congue quis elit a convallis. Vestibulum pretium eros quis elementum congue. Cras vitae ultrices urna. Sed lorem magna, auctor nec
  rutrum a, semper sit amet lectus. Morbi tincidunt sollicitudin arcu at molestie. Nunc imperdiet bibendum metus, a facilisis massa condimentum et.
</div>
```

Até aí tudo bem, porém quando testo no mobile ele não tem o mesmo efeito. Existe alguma maneira de localizar a janela do celular e utilizar o método .scroll? Encontrei algumas respostas falando sobre o 'touchmove' porém testando no meu celular com o phonegap não funcionou.

Answer (score 0):

Tente fazer assim:

```
$(document).on("scrollstart", function (e) {
  var active = $.mobile.activePage[0].id;
  if (active == "pg_remote-address-book") {
    $('.exemplo').css('color', "black");
  } else {
    $('.exemplo').css('color', "red");
  }
});
```

Testei e deu certo.

[**JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/SamirChaves/wqent4aL/1/).

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20275937/capture-scroll-event-on-a-particular-jquery-mobile-page).